# A multiplication of vectors

Tags: matrices, vectors, matrix-calculus

From page 219, 'Machine Learning' by Murphy:

$$\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Xw})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Xw})=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{w}^T(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{w}^T(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}).$$

Is there an easy was to see that this equality holds, without having to write out generic elements of both sides and seeing that they turn out to be the same?

Comment: Is that half of the first term on the right hand side or half of everything? Is $y^T$ orthogonal to $y-Xw$ by any chance?

Comment: Hm. Isn't the RHS $0$ when $\mathbf w = 0$, and the LHS not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked my lecturer, and it turns out it's a misprint - the RHS is missing a $\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y}$ term. Now it makes sense!